Making all submitted files a file chip instead of URL
I created a google forms linked to a spreadsheet called Submissions. The problem is that when files are submitted through the google form, they are automatically uploaded to the spreadsheet as a link that extends well beyond the cell borders.
I found a youtube video that said to make a second sheet and use the arrayformula function to be able to format the data from the first spreadsheet Submissions to look however I would like it to look. This works, however the files still come in as a url that extends well beyond the cell borders. I would like for every file in E through K (starting at row 2 all the way to row 50) to automatically be a file chip when it takes the data from the Submissions spreadsheet. Is there an apps script code for this? I do not know how to write any code, I am only going off of what I can find on youtube.
OR - is there an apps script code that I can use on the original spreadsheet that receives the submissions data to make all files into file chips so that I do not have to use a second sheet/arrayformula?
Second sheet with arrayfunction

As I understand it, file smart chips are limited to Sheets, Docs and Presentations. It's not possible to create a smart chip for other Workspace apps nor for "files" generally. In addition, certain functionality of smart chips is limited to Enterprise and Education versions of Workspace.

The URL of a Forms upload is long (something like: "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1P3WwC39iWmXpZGzzIUjfJ6a-HoJqFkta"). But it does contain valuable information. Why not just leave the url as-is and format the cell/column as "Wrapping>Clip" to limit the display to the width of the column.

Chips can only be added by using the Google Sheets UI.
If you only have 50 rows, consider using HYPERLINK. Just so you know, this function doesn't work with arrays of URLs, so you should add one formula for each URL. Use relative references, then do a fill down and fill right.
An alternative using Google Apps Script is to format the cell content as rich text by using Class RichTextValueBuilder.
Related

How to add a link to a spreadsheet cell using Google Apps Script

